# rails has_many through on a new element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following model:

```
class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :party_characters
  has_many :characters, :through => :party_characters
  ...
```

And on my controller I have the following code:

```
def new
  @party = Party.new
  p @party.characters.any?
  p @party.characters
  p @party.characters.any?
  ...
```

That writes the following to the console:

```
true
[]
false
```

Why does the `any?` method returns true before the print and false after?

Comment: it returns 
false
[]
false on my box.

Comment: @bento if it is any help i'm using ruby 1.9.3p0 and rails 3.2.6

Comment: should be close enough, as I said, couldn't reproduce it - can you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried the same thing on the console and got the following results

```
1.9.3p0 :003 > p = Party.new
 => #<Party id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
1.9.3p0 :004 > p.characters.any?
   (17.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "characters" INNER JOIN "party_characters" ON "characters"."id" = "party_characters"."character_id" WHERE "party_characters"."party_id" IS NULL
 => true 
1.9.3p0 :005 > p.characters
 => [] 
1.9.3p0 :006 > p.characters.any?
 => false
```

So I decided to check what I had on the party_characters table and found entries with a valid character_id but with a nil party id. I removed those and everything works as supposed.